# Cannot display image in GridView using Picasso (Callback logs Success!)

Tags: android, gridview, picasso

I want to display some images from a URL in a GridView, I logged everything and it looks like it works (the adapter is loaded, Picasso Callback logs Success, the URL is correct, etc) but the image is not displayed. I have no idea what I did wrong, I'm sure it's obvious to you but I stared at this for hours and nothing.

```
public class GridImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MovieObj> {

    Context mContext;

    private static final String LOG_TAG = GridImageAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    public GridImageAdapter(Activity context, List<MovieObj> movieObjects){

        super(context, 0, movieObjects);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        MovieObj currentMovie = getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.grid_item_movie_poster, parent, false);

        }

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);


        String posterId = currentMovie.getPosterId();

        String posterUrl = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185" + posterId;


        Picasso.with(mContext).load(posterUrl).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_ic).error(R.drawable.placeholder_ic).into(imageView, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Image Loaded");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Does not load");
            }
        });
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, posterUrl);
        return convertView;

    }
}
```

In the fragment: